# sessionStorage works but returns "undefined" in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

I just built a jquery plugin to handle some data storages.
When I try to read from storage, the result is the read item data.

But when I add

```
sessionStorage.setItem('test','some data');
```

or remove

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('test');
```

an item, I always get `undefined` in the `console.log`

How can I get rid of the undefined?

What I tried was

```
var result = sessionStorage.setItem('test','some data');
```

though this would print it to a var but it doesn't.

My code:

```
(function ($) {
    
    $.storage = {
    
        add: function(name,value){

            if(typeof value === 'object' )
            {   
                /** convert object to json **/
                value = JSON.stringify(value);
            }
            /** add to storage **/
            sessionStorage.setItem(name,value);
        },
        
        read: function(name){
        
            /** read from storage **/
            var item = sessionStorage.getItem(name);
                try {
                    item = $.parseJSON(item);
                }catch(e){}
            return item;
        },
        
        remove: function(name){
            /** delete from storage **/
            sessionStorage.removeItem(name);
        },
        
        clear: function(){
            /** clear storage **/
            sessionStorage.clear();
        }
        
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: "how can i get rid of the undefined, any ideas ???" — Why do you want to?

Comment: because it seams to be wrong... when i programm, run my application and undefined appears several times...

Comment: @Dwza, I have create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/mCNFT/ using your code. Can you reproduce your problem in fiddle. Also note `sessionStorage` is supported in IE8+ browser see http://caniuse.com/#search=sessionStorage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setItem` and `removeItem` doesn't return any value. Thus you are getting `undefined`. Also note `removeItem` only accept one parameter.

[Reference](https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/), Here is function sign for above methods

**setItem(key:string, data:string):void**

> This public method stores data via specified key. Please note that if key was already stored, it will overwrite it. Another thing to consider is that if we store a key, and via sessionStorage.key(0) we obtain that key, then we store another key/data and finally we store again the first key, sessionStorage.key(0) will return the second key/data stored, and not the first one.

**removeItem(key:string):void**

> This public method simply removes a key and related data from the storage.

Comment: parameter for remove was a copy paste typo. sorry. but why do i get a undefined in console when i call these functions ?

Comment: @Dwza — For the reason described in the very first sentence of this answer!

Comment: @Quentin i don't want to return anyting. not even a undefined. the things what Satpal sayed was clear from beginning... but the question is: can i avoid this...

Comment: @Dwza — `undefined` **is** nothing. You can't have what you want.

Comment: i have the feeling i don't understand you or you don't understand me... i know undefined **is** nothing. but its my thing if i call console.log() or not. so why should i call a empty console.log ? no reason! that's why i want to avoid the returned undefine. if i write a jquery function it also return none!

Comment: Umm. If you don't want to log a value when that value is undefined, then use an if statement to test if the value is undefined before you log it.

Comment: @Satpal i added it to my post :)

Comment: @Quentin, i don't want to log it... i just want to do a action. see my source for my plugin. i have programmed a huge project and its kind of annoying to recive undefined's when im debugging because i don't see where they come from, it could be a empty var or what ever... so that's the reason why i want to avoid this for further debugs

Comment: I have even less idea about what you want now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52189/discussion-between-dwza-and-quentin)

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = sessionStorage.setItem('test','some data');
```

does not return anything.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('test','some data');
```

assigns value to `'test'`therefore the right hand side does not have any value.
What you want is

```
sessionStorage.setItem('test','some data');
var result = sessionStorage.getItem('test'); //<- here the right hand side is 'some data'
```

Comment: It's not an invalid statement, it's just that that the `setItem` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: I know it is years ago but... the "var result" was just an attempt to surppress the "undefined" that was shown in the console. but i guess i fixed it.